# How to remove the dependency on a Java enum's values?

Tags: java, serialization, enums, classloader, dependency-management

[*Mind the gap:* I know that the best solution would be to get rid of the enum completely, but that's not an option for today as mentioned in the comments, but it is planned for the (far) future.]

We have two deployment units: frontend and backend. The frontend uses an enum and calls an EJB service at the backend with the enum as a parameter. But the enum changes frequently, so we don't want the backend to know its values.

**String constants**

A possible solution would be to use String constants insteadof enums, but that would cause a lot of little changes at the frontend. I'm searching a solution, which causes as few changes as possible in the frontend.

**Wrapper class**

Another solution is the usage of a wrapper class with the same interface as an enum. The enum becomes an wrapper class and the enum values become constants within that wrapper. I had to write some deserialization code to ensure object identity (as enums do), but I don't know if it is a correct solution. What if different classloaders are used?
The wrapper class will implement a Java interface, which will replace the enum in the backend. But will the deserialiaztion code execute in the backend even so?

Example for a wrapper class:

```
public class Locomotion implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6359307469030924650L;

    public static final List<Locomotion> list = new ArrayList<Locomotion>();

    public static final Locomotion CAR = createValue(4654L);
    public static final Locomotion CYCLE = createValue(34235656L);
    public static final Locomotion FEET = createValue(87687L);

    public static final Locomotion createValue(long type) {
        Locomotion enumValue = new Locomotion(type);
        list.add(enumValue);
        return enumValue;
    }

    private final long ppId;

    private Locomotion(long type) {
        this.ppId = type;
    }

    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        for (Locomotion enumValue : list) {
            if (this.equals(enumValue)) {
                return enumValue;
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Unknown enum value '" + ppId + "'");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (ppId ^ (ppId >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Locomotion)) {
            return false;
        }
        Locomotion other = (Locomotion) obj;
        if (ppId != other.ppId) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Did you already had the same problem? How did you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me see if I understand. You said that

> "The frontend uses an enum and calls
>   an EJB service at the backend with the
>   enum as a parameter. But the enum
>   changes frequently, so we don't want
>   the backend to know its values"

When you say "values" I assume you are referring to the numeric value you pass in the enum constructor and not to the enum constants themselves.

Therefore, this implies that the frontend and the backend will have two different versions of the enum class, but the enum constants in them will be the same.

I am only assuming the communication is via RMI (but this is not entirely clear in your post).

Now, serialization/deserialization of enums works different than with other objects. According to the Java Serialization Specification, when a enum is serialized, only its name is serialized. And when it is deserialized, it is built using the Enum.valueOf(name) method.

So, your original wrapper proposal would not work, because the server, due to stipulated serialization of Enums will never know the actual value of the enums in the client.

Bottom line, if you intend to pass an enum to the server there is no possible way to do what you pretend to do because the values in the frontend will never reach the backend if serialization is implied.

If RMI is implied, a good solution would be to use code mobility, this way you could place the problematic class in a repository accessible to both, server and client, and when the frontend developers change the class definition, you can publish the class in the repository and the server can get it from there.

See this article about dynamic code downloading using code base property in RMI
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html

Another possible solution is that you could stop using a Java Enum and use Java class with final constants, as we used to do in the old days before enums, and that way you can ensure that its values will be properly serialized when they are are sent to the backend.

Somewhat like this

```
public class Fruit implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public final Fruit ORANGE = new Fruit("orange");
    public final Fruit LEMON = new Fruit("lemon");

    private String name;

    private Fruit(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This way you can be in full control of what happens upon deserialization and your wrapper pattern might work this way.

This type of construction cannot substitute an enum completely, for instance, it cannot be used in switch statements. But, if this is an issue, you could use this object as the parameter sent to the server, and let the server rebuild the enum out of it with its version of the enum class.

Your enum, therefore, could have two new methods, one to build Java instances out of the enum itself:

```
public static Fruit toFruit(FruitEnum enum);
public FruitEnum valueOf(Fruit fruit);
```

And you can use those to convert back and forth versions of the parameter for the server.

Comment: +1 for the enum serialization logic and the "switch problem". But rebuilding an enum on the server side would make the whole thing pointless, as I still would have to redeploy when a new value is added.

Comment: @Chris If you really intend to keep the enum as parameter, due to serialization, there is no way to do it. You still have code mobility. If that does not make it for you, only Mandrake would :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd request, as i would think the server should know about the values of what is going into the database, but ok, i'll play along. Perhaps you could do this

```
public enum Giant {Fee, Fi, Fo, Fum};

public void client() {
    Giant giant = Giant.Fee;
    server(giant);
}

public void server(Enum e) {
    String valueForDB = e.name();
        //or perhaps
    String valueForDB = e.toString();
}
```

Comment: The server doesn't need to know which values are allowed, because he uses the enum just as an id to get relevant informations from a database. That may sound even more crazy. But it's an historic dept, which we cannot get rid of easily. (I wouldn't create an enum for an id which is stored in a database...)

Comment: That certainly would work, but the frontend guys insist on a strongly typed interface. With that interface any enum may be passed. But I will discuss that approach.

Comment: Marshalling parameters between frontend and EJB backend may require serialization, this in turn needs the same class incl. its *version*! So I'm afraid this hier is not a solution, because server will no be able to get e.name/e.toString if it doesn't know the exact enum Giant that the frontend uses.

Comment: It don't have to be an enum. It could be of another type, which acts the same way as an enum does.

Answer (score 1):

For data transfer between frontend and backend both need to use the same class versions because of possible serialization during marshalling parameters. So again they have to know exactly the same enums or whatever other classes you try to use. Switching enums to something different won't work either. You have to set on a known class identiy for both.

So if the server should do actions based on some kind of processing/calculating the values of the parameters use strings or whatever other non-changing class you decide on and put your values inside: string of characters, array of numbers or whatever.

So if you put your database id inside the wrapper object the server will be able to get the objects out of the database. But still - they both need exact the same version of the wrapper class in their classpaths.

Comment: I know that there is a design flaw. Refactoring it will require a bigger effort. So for now your arguments are part of the problem not of the solution.

Comment: I have just edited away this with the design flaw - well it is, but it was not a part of the question. But I'm glad you've agreed :-)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I can't be too exact because I don't see your code but in my experience something that changes like that should be external data, not enums.

What I almost always find is that if I externalize the information that was in the enums, then I have to externalize a few other pieces as well, but after doing it all I end up factoring away a LOT of code.

Any time you actually use the values of an enum you are almost certainly writing duplicate code.  What I mean is that if you have enums like "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS"...

The ONLY way they can be used in your code is in something like a switch statement:

```
switch(card.suit)
case Suit.HEARTS:
    load_graphic(Suit.HEARTS);
    // or better yet:
    Suit.HEARTS.loadGraphic();
    break;
case Suit.SPADES:
    Suit.SPADES.loadGraphic();

...
```

Now, this is obviously stupid but I made the stupid constraint to say that you USED the values in the code.  My assertion is that if you don't USE the values you don't need an enum--Let's not use the values in code and see:

```
card.suit.loadGraphic();
```

Wow, all gone.  But suddenly, the entire point of using an enum is gone--instead you get rid of the whole class preload a "Suit" factory with 4 instances from a text file with strings like "Heart.png" and "Spade.png".

Nearly every time I use enums I end up factoring them out like this.

I'm not saying there isn't any code that can benefit from enums--but the better that I get at factoring code and externalizing data, the less I can imagine really needing them.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't see how this is related to the question. I even explained, that I thought about that and cannot do it (see #String constants).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was suggesting you move towards your refactoring/wrapper class solution and then attempt to extract the initializing data from code into data.  Also it's nice to kind of point things like this out now and then to people who are considering using enums and might be viewing such a question.